# Three.js Canvas Lines Example Tweak

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

This is most likely better posted in a forum, but the Three.js Google Group seems dead and I'm not aware of any others so apologies in advance. Feel free to let me know of a better place to post more generic questions.

I'm curious how one would make this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_lines fill a cube's space instead of a sphere? Is there an easy way to go about this with this example or would it require a lot of changes?

Comment: Wait. There is a Three.js Google Group?

Comment: Yeah, but hardly anything there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/threejs and after I googled that again I ran across this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/211 There's an IRC room? EFNet? lol

Comment: Freenode! http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=three.js ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.normalize();
particle.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 10 + 450 );
```

With this:

```
particle.position.x = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
particle.position.y = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
particle.position.z = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
```

This code places the points at the edges of the box:

```
particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
particle.position.normalize();
particle.position.multiplyScalar( 500 );
particle.position.clamp(
    new THREE.Vector3( -250, -250, -250 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  250,  250,  250 )
);
```

Comment: I haven't fully wrapped my head around this math, but thanks for the prompt reply @mrdoob! multiplyScalar is very straightforward, can you tell me where I can find docs on the normalize method?

Comment: Any idea how I can push more of the dots to the "walls" of the cube to more visually create a side of the cube?